# Shutting down Windows 7 automatically 10 minutes from now

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, delayed-execution

Is there a way to make Windows 7 do this: "10 minutes from now, close all applications and shut down (or hibernate), no matter what input you get from the keyboard or the mouse"? It's OK if the user can revert the shutdown order during the 10 minute period, but once the shutdown begins there should be no turning back.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `shutdown` command line command is what you're after, with `/t 600` you'll get a 600 second (10 minute) delay other options define the shutdown process. In your case I suspect you'll want `shutdown /t 600 /s`.

Comment: some apps MIGHT stop shutdown. notepad comes to mind.

Comment: @The Geek: It's not Notepad itself but the "Do you want to save?" dialog box. This is, AFAIK, common to all programs and does make sense. However, 1) IIRC, Windows 7 does not allow programs to stop shutdowns like that anymore; 2) `shutdown /f`

Comment: chrome browser can as well I believe

Comment: is there a reason you are using /t instead of -t ?

Answer (score 3):

As Havok stated, you can just use the Shutdown switch from command prompt. See options below.
[image]

Run from cmd.exe or just put into a .bat script as below (and you could just add this .bat to Windows scheduler if you wanted to schedule) - remove the "pause" if you want it to run straight away:

```
@cd /
@cls
@echo #Shutdown 10min script#
@pause
@shutdown /t 600 /s
```

Comment: you can use command > foo.txt to direct output to a text file for easy and pasting

Comment: Agreed, but for some reason came out garbled hence pic ;-)

Comment: Wrap it in `<pre>` `</pre>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of automatical shutdown programs on the net. You can use one of them; for example: [Sweet Dreams](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Launchers-Shutdown-Tools/Sweet-Dreams.shtml).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by following the simple steps below:

1. Go to run (Win + r)
2. Type `shutdown -s -t 600` and hit enter

The computer will shut down in exactly 10 minutes (600 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

The first response was adequate.  Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and then type `shutdown /t "desired duration" /s` in the field. Replace *"desired duration"* with the amount of seconds you wish your PC to turn off and press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script for myself to shutdown the computer after a time interval that I set. this is the code:

```
:shutdown_sequence
set /p TM="Enter a time to shut down:"
set /a TM1=TM*60
echo I will shutdown the computer in %TM% minutes and in seconds: %TM1% 
shutdown -s -f -t %TM1%
pause
exit
goto:eof
```

Comment: Can you explain how the OP would execute this code?

Comment: Why do you have a useless `goto:eof` at the end of your batch file?